# New site based on data from another - the best system architecture?

Tags: django, web-services, web, content-management-system

So here's the thing:

1. I have a website, let's call it Catalogue. It is an advanced product catalogue with a lot of items in it. It works on php based CMS, it wasn't done by me and is fairly complete and complicated system. What is important, it has user authentification system and a lot of users in the database. You can not access most of the products unless you are logged in.
2. I want to have another website and I want to build this one on my own. It will contain some additional data for the products, extended download section and some media too. I want to build it with Django.

This other website is going to use Catalogue's database a lot:
- it needs to authorize users using their login/pass from the Catalogue
- It will need customers data to customize their views.

I don't have big experience in building more advanced systems. Could you, experienced programmers tell how would you do that?

Specifically, I'm concerned about database: should I only use the original database? And merge all django related stuff in it? Will it affect Catalogue?
Is it generally good idea?

As I've mentioned I'm going to use user data from Catalogue's database to authenticate users. Are there some security concerns with this idea?

I intuitively feel that I should use one database rather then two. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Please let me know what you think about such idea. Maybe it's not worth pursuing and should be done in a completely different way?

Thanks,

C

Comment: Is this new website being made just to learn Django and get experience, or to provide some new functionality? Also, is this going to be on the same URL, or something different? I will give a longer answer shortly.

Comment: Begin with something simple, firstly write a parser in Python which logs into the external website, extracts some data and saves it into the local db. If you manage to do it then you can think about bigger django app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this, and various risks that you need to weigh out prior to making a decision. Because this is your first time, there is a high risk of making mistakes (no offense, just the way it is) and as such, it is probably not the best idea to make modifications to a database that is already used in production. If you make a change, it could negatively impact the other website, and you may struggle figuring out what caused the change or how to recover from it.

You can still (technically) use the same actual database server, and simply use a different database so that it is all stored in the same place. You may encounter issues though depending on how the database is locked down, so you will want to take into consideration access to the database and things of that nature. You can also just as easily use a different database and keep everything separate.

Cons of using the same database include the fact that whichever database you use has a maximum number of connections and IO, so if your new site becomes successful, that could cause for the other site to slow in regards to query time and things of that nature.

In respect to authentication, there are a few routes you can take. In the case where you use a separate db, you can perform actual reads from the database to check authentication and permissions and things of that nature. You could also create an API for the old website, and simply make the new website use that API for authentication.

All in all, my opinion would be to use a different DB, and use the old DB for read-only purposes. Later, you could maybe create an API that both applications can work on top of to limit code duplication. Trying to merge, though, provides a large potential for issues though, especially if you are new to the system.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.